# 30 amp 110 breaker

Tags: electrical, electrical-panel

I just purchase a band saw that has a motor that is 100/220 (currently setup for 220) which I figured I would easily add a 220 outlet in my garage or switch to 110. Well, its become a little more difficult than that, I think. I am pretty handy and have done lots of electrical wiring but when it comes to amps/watts and the like, I ain't no Bob Villa (sorry, bad joke).

My problem is, I think, that I am out of empty breaker spaces in my garage's breaker box to add a 220 so I am stuck with 110.

Currently the top-right is for the outlets in the garage and it is 20 amp.
[image: Breaker Box in garage]

Here is the current plug for 220 on the band saw. I know I would have to rewire the motor for 110 and change the plug.
[image: Current Plug]

Here is the motor information
[image: Motor information]

So if I read this right, for 220 I only need 14 amp but for 110, I would have to handle 28 amps.

My question is this: Can I run this motor on the current 20 amp (110) or is there just no way?

Does anyone have an ideas?

Comment: How about a panel upgrade (or the addition of a subpanel)? If you're willing to spend ~$100, you can get yourself a great panel with a thousand spaces that @Harper would be proud of. The best part is that it's probably your best solution overall. Running on 110V would trip your breaker (inrush current > 20A) and rewiring for a 30A breaker would be a pain, so any reason *not* to rewire for a new panel?

Comment: What is the designation and specification of that plug and what receptacle(s) will it fit into?

Comment: @JimStewart Not sure what that means. The guy I got it from was an electrician and said it was 220. The plug says 20A_250V.

Comment: @Steve he is probably asking what type of [NEMA connector](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NEMA_connector) you want to use - that Wiki link has a nifty [chart](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NEMA_connector#/media/File:NEMA_simplified_pins.svg) which lists the vast majority of plugs you are likely to encounter in North American residential wiring.

Comment: @JimStewart I planned on sticking with the same 220 that was on there unless I had to go to 110. Then, I have no idea. I have never seen a 110 that could take 30A. Figured the guy at the store could help me with that. My bigger concern was getting the breaker and wire figured out.

Comment: A NEMA 5-30 could take 30A...

Comment: Have you had the cover off this panel? Is it possible that there are more breaker slots available with a different cover?

Comment: @JimStewart No I have not. I did think about it but with no more open slots on the front I didn't think it was plausible.

Comment: I just wondered about all that space seemingly covered up. It is not safe to remove a cover unless you are experienced and take proper safety precautions. I am not encouraging you to do this yourself.  I wonder if the model info on the panel would lead to more information.

Comment: I see a 30-A 2 pole presumably 240 V breaker on the right and another double breaker on the left. What are those used for?

Comment: @JimStewart One is for my well pump and the other is for a sub-panel in an out-building.

Comment: @HariGanti I'm going to go with your idea and either upgrade the box or put in a sub-panel. Probably the first. Thanks everyone for the help.

Comment: They do make double stuff or tandem breakers for that panel, by replacing all 4 with of the singles with double stuff this will open up 2 slots and a double pole 20 can be used as the load would be 14 amps as long as the wire to the existing outlet is 12 awg. A 120v 30 amp will require rewiring to a larger wire size I would the 28 amp FLA will trip on a 30a breaker because motors draw 3 to 5 times there FLA on startup. Check the panel and see if it has a dual listing like 8 /16 if all locations can be double stuffed you need at least 8/12 for this as QO double stuff have a rejection device.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> My question is this: Can I run this motor on the current 20 amp (110) or is there just no way?
>
> Does anyone have an ideas?

Short answer: No

The motor leads in the connection box on the saw need to be changed to the 110 volt configuration, the plug needs to be changed to a 125 volt 30 amp plug and the breaker would have to be upsized to a 30 amp. Then the wiring to the receptacle needs to be #10 wire.

Good luck with your project!

Answer (score -2):

Looks like you can swap one of those fat single breakers for a quad, like this:

[image]

In a double width space you get three breakers (a tandem for the 220V and two single phase breakers).  Then ditch two single breakers for another tandem breaker and you're done.

Comment: Those are QOs in the OPs panel, not Homelines.  He could consolidate a couple of spaces into QOTs, but quadruplex breakers do not exist in the QO line...